# AndroidTV emulator UnknownHostException when accessing internet (OSx 10.11)

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

I am having trouble getting access to the internet from my AndroidTV AVD.

The same application runs without problems on my Nexus Player - so the code is working, and the permissions are ok. 
I just cannot bring the Nexus Player with me at all times (commuting by train for 3 hours a day) - so being able to use the emulator is important to me.

I start it like this:
./emulator -avd Android_TV_1080p_API_23 -netspeed full -netdelay none -wipe-data -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 -shell

If I do a simple test like

```
new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection().getInputStream();
```

It fails with UnknownHostException.

If I configure a proxy server on my host machine and add the -http-proxy http://10.0.2.2:8888 to the emulator args I get a

```
Network is unreachable error:
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8888): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable).
```

I get the same ENETUNREACH error if I remove the -http-proxy argument and use the IP-address of the www.google.com server instead of the DNS name. So I don't think it is a DNS issue.

I have tried disabling all other NICs on my host machine - and moving the current NIC up to the top in the Order in OSx settings.

I also tried deleting my AVD and creating a new one for AndroidTV - no dice.

If I start the AVD and open AndroidTV settings the Wifi says Off - I can turn it on without errors - but if I exit the settings and re-open them it is off when I return.

I can create an Android Tablet avd on the same machine and access the internet just fine - but cannot access the internet in any of the AndroidTV avds I tried creating.

It is not just my own app that cannot access the internet it is the entire emulator. If I in the AndroidTV emulator goes to Settings->About->Ads->Ads by Google I get an error "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". 
On my Nexus Player I get a web browser that shows a Google page when I access that menu.

Is it a bug in AndroidTV emulator, or what am I missing?

Comment: If I create standard Android AVD's and open the browser in them they can access the internet (and my host machine proxy) just fine. It seems to only be related to AndroidTV AVDs.

Comment: I tried all suggestions I could find in here and none of them worked for me. So ended up creating an issue in the Android issue tracker - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197004